# Status 500 while Load testing using Gatling

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I have a simple login request like this:

```
.exec(http("login")
            .post("/j_spring_security_check")
            .formParam("j_username", "${email}")
            .formParam("j_password", "${password}")
            .formParam("CSRFToken", "${CSRFToken}"))    
        .pause(4)
```

Where, ${email} and ${password} is parametrised from a csv file and ${CSRFToken} is a dynamic, session specific token which has been co-related.

When I run a simple test, this request works fine. But when I run a load test, few (very few 5/850) of the requests fails saying `'status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 500'`. Does it mean anything to anyone? Why do I get this error and what does it imply?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 5xx error usually means that the server had a problem with the request.  Outside of that it's tough to say; are you testing this on a remote server or is this local?

Comment: Yes, I am able to figure it out that it is something related to server. But, unable to diagnose the cause.BTW, I am testing on a remote server.

Comment: You're going to need access to the server logs to figure it out.  I can generalize at least what's going on in an answer at a later time.

Comment: Al right! let me try and dig into server logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5xx errors indicate that the server you're testing on has encountered an error in processing your request.  This doesn't normally have to do with your input - the server should be robust enough against any kind of request - but rather an issue with processing it somewhere.

This is external to your testing and you would need to ask questions of the developers who wrote that piece of code, and figure out why it could be erroring out.